# How to sum all elements in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

this is an array which is given:

```
let arrayNumbers = [ 5, 7, 
        [ 4, [2], 8, [1,3], 2 ], 
        [ 9, [] ], 
        1, 8
      ];
```

and the output must be `50`

This code must be WITHOUT Array.isArray;

```
let sum = 0;
function treeSum(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === false) {
            treeSum(array[i]);
        } else {
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

treeSum(arrayNumbers);
```

Help, please with an idea or code, thanks.

Comment: why either "*count array elements*" or get sum of all? and why `5`?

Comment: `arrayNumbers.flat(Infinity).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)` ?

Comment: is 50, im trying to fix this

Comment: Yes, it's the sum of all elements.

Comment: Is it worth explaining why you can't use `Array.isArray`? It's supported all the way down to IE9.

Comment: If `Array.isArray` cannot be used, then what else cannot be used either? `flat`, `flatMap`, `reduce`, recursion, `typeof`, `instanceof`, `constructor`, ...? Such requirements make no sense without more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a local `sum` variable as well to prevent duplicate adding of nested sums.

You could check if the item

- is an instance of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) with the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), of

  ```js
  function treeSum(array) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          sum += array[i] instanceof Array ? treeSum(array[i]) : array[i];
      }
      return sum;
  }

  let arrayNumbers = [5, 7, [4, [2], 8, [1, 3], 2],  [9, []], 1, 8];

  console.log(treeSum(arrayNumbers));
  ```
- has `Array` as [`Object#constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor).

  ```js
  function treeSum(array) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          sum += array[i].constructor === Array ? treeSum(array[i]) : array[i];
      }
      return sum;
  }

  let arrayNumbers = [5, 7, [4, [2], 8, [1, 3], 2],  [9, []], 1, 8];

  console.log(treeSum(arrayNumbers));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Flatten and reduce the array as below:-

```
var sum = arrayNumbers.flat(Infinity).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `flat` the list then use `reduce` method to obtain the sum.

You can use `if (item.map)` condition in order to check if it's array.

```js
let arrayNumbers = [ 5, 7, 
        [ 4, [2], 8, [1,3], 2 ], 
        [ 9, [] ], 
        1, 8
      ];
const flatArray = (arr) => {
    const res = []
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (item.map) {
            const subRes = flatArray(item)
            res.push(...subRes)
        } else {
            res.push(item)
        }
    }
    return res;
}      
console.log(flatArray(arrayNumbers).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
```

Comment: I cannot do it like this also, that's the problem(

Comment: `Array#reduce` throws an error against an empty array if you don't have an initial value. So you should probably set `0` as an initial value of your reducer. Note that `Number([])` returns `0` so this would be consistent with how JavaScript would convert an empty array into a number.

Comment: @PStarter, I used `if (item.map)` to check if it's array.

Comment: @customcommander, the OP says `This code must be WITHOUT Array.isArray;`

Comment: @customcommander, one possible alternative could be `typeof arr.map === 'function'`

Comment: If you can't use `Array.isArray`, you probably can't use `Array#reduce` either. That restriction is weird though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion. So you need to check whether iterated element is array. If it is array, then run `sumArray` method again, otherwise you can sum up value:

```
const sumArray = (arr) => {
  let sum = 0;
  arr.forEach(element => {
    if (typeof element != 'number') {
        sum += sumArray(element);
    } else {
      sum += element
      return sum;
    }
  });
  return sum;
}


console.log(sumArray(arrayNumbers));
```

An example:

```js
let arrayNumbers = [ 5, 7,
  [ 4, [2], 8, [1,3], 2 ],
  [ 9, [] ],
  1, 8
];

const sumArray = (arr) => {
  let sum = 0;
  arr.forEach(element => {
    if (typeof element != 'number') {
        sum += sumArray(element);
    } else {
      sum += element
      return sum;
    }
  });
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumArray(arrayNumbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the combination of 'join', 'split' and reduce

```js
var t =[ 5, 7, 
        [ 4, [2], 8, [1,3], 2 ], 
        [ 9, [] ], 
        1, 8
      ].join().split(',').reduce(function(a,b) { return parseInt(a?a:"0") + parseInt(b?b:"0")})
      
 console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick that will work on any array depth is to  `join` to a string.
Then use `match` to get the numbers.
Then `reduce` those numbers to a sum.

**Example snippet:**

```js
let arrayNumbers = [ 5, 7, 
    [ 4, [2], 8, [1,3], 2 ], 
    [ 9, [] ], 
    1, 8
  ];
  
let sum = arrayNumbers
        .join()
        .match(/\d+/g)
        .reduce((acc, x) => acc + parseInt(x), 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Recursion version using `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let arrayNumbers = [5, 7, [4, [2], 8, [1, 3], 2], [9, []], 1, 8];

function treeSum(array) {
  return array.reduce(
    (sum, n) =>
      sum +
      (typeof n === "number"
        ? // n is a number
          n
        : // n is an array
          treeSum(n)),
    0
  );
}

console.log(treeSum(arrayNumbers) === 50);
```

## Recursion version using `for...of`

```js
let arrayNumbers = [5, 7, [4, [2], 8, [1, 3], 2], [9, []], 1, 8];

function treeSum(array, sum = 0) {
  for (const n of array) {
    sum += typeof n === "number" ? n : treeSum(n);
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(treeSum(arrayNumbers) === 50);
```

## Iteration version

```js
let arrayNumbers = [5, 7, [4, [2], 8, [1, 3], 2], [9, []], 1, 8];

function treeSum(array) {
  let sum = 0;

  do {
    // not summed values
    let values = [];
    for (const n of array) {
      if (typeof n === "number") sum += n;
      else values = values.concat(n);
    }
    array = values;
  } while (array.length > 0);

  return sum;
}

console.log(treeSum(arrayNumbers) === 50);
```

## Oneline solution using `Array.prototype.flat`

```
let arrayNumbers = [5, 7, [4, [2], 8, [1, 3], 2], [9, []], 1, 8];

function treeSum(array) {
  return array.flat(Infinity).reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0);
}

console.log(treeSum(arrayNumbers) === 50);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) function:

```
var flat = arrayNumbers.flat(Infinity);
var sum = flat.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Why `.flat().flat()` when you can specify a depth? A reducer without an initial value will throw an error if the array is empty. You should specify `0` as an initial value.

Comment: Thanks for the depth suggestion, and will not give error because it is already have value, otherwise you can use the default value